# Issues in building numpy from source on Windows

Tags: python, numpy, build

I am trying to build numpy 1.26.0 on windows platform but facing lots of challenges. could someone please help me with it.

1. I built openblas  using https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire/wiki/CBLAS-for-Windows
   installed rtools to get gfortran and gcc along with  microsoft visual studios.

I was able to built openbals successfully and installed it -

```
OpenBLAS build complete. (BLAS CBLAS LAPACK LAPACKE)

            OS               ... WINNT
            Architecture     ... x86_64
            BINARY           ... 64bit
            C compiler       ... GCC  (cmd & version : cc.exe (Built by Jeroen for the R-project) 10.3.0)
            Fortran compiler ... GFORTRAN  (cmd & version : GNU Fortran (Built by Jeroen for the R-project) 10.3.0)
            Library Name     ... libopenblas_zenp-r0.3.20.a (Multi-threading; Max num-threads is 2)
```

2. Now when I am trying to build numpy 1.26.0 whl file after downloading  numpy source code -

```
python -m build --wheel --no-isolation .
```

I am hitting below issues though build is able to get openblas lib but still having issues -

```
Library m found: NO
Found pkg-config: C:\rtools40\ucrt64\bin\pkg-config.EXE (0.29.2)
Run-time dependency openblas found: YES 0.3.20
Checking if "CBLAS" with dependency openblas: links: NO
Found CMake: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE (3.17.20032601)
WARNING: CMake Toolchain: Failed to determine CMake compilers state
Run-time dependency cblas found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)

numpy\1.26.0\numpy-1.26.0\numpy\meson.build:189:4: ERROR: Problem encountered: No CBLAS interface detected! Install a BLAS library with CBLAS support, or use the `allow-noblas` build option (note, this may be up to 100x slower for some linear algebra operations).
```

P.S. I know there is already a whl file provided by pypi.org but I do not want to use it.

#numpy

Already mentioned tried steps in problem

Answer (score 0):

The build uses pkg-config to detect OpenBLAS, and is failing to find CBLAS. Check the meson build log in build/meson-logs for more details about what might be going wrong. My guess is that you are using MSVC but OpenBLAS is only built for gcc (no openblas.lib import library). For a hint as to what is involved in creating the import library, see [these steps](https://github.com/MacPython/openblas-libs/blob/main/tools/build_openblas.sh#L106) in the build of OpenBLAS used by NumPy and SciPy.